# glext.h on Windows

Tags: windows, opengl, windows-10

I have Linux OpenGL application which uses glext.h. That header is installed in the standard system location: `/usr/include/GL/glext.h` I don't use any third party library for loading GL functions, I just use `glXGetProcAddress`. I would like to port my application to Windows 10 but there is no glext.h. Why Windows 10 doesn't contain that header ? It looks like that the best solution is copy glext.h to my application sources.

Comment: download needed headers from [nVidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-opengl-specs) or from https://www.opengl.org// ... OS does not include C++ header files ... that would make no sense instead they should be installed into your programming IDE/environment in form of SDKs ...